# Canvas Rotate, toDataUrl, and then Crop is ruining image quality

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, canvas

I have an image that I'm allowing users to rotate 90 degrees in any direction. Every time they rotate, I use canvas to perform the image manipulations and then save the data returned by the `canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1)`.

The problem is that the image quality decreases every time I rotate the image.

My end goal is to rotate a rectangular image without losing image quality and also saving the new data url.

```
function rotateAndSave(image: HTMLImageElement, degrees: number): string {
  const imageWidth = image.naturalWidth;
  const imageHeight = image.naturalHeight;
  const startedHorizontalEndedVertical = imageWidth > imageHeight;
  const canvasSize = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? imageWidth : imageHeight;

  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = canvasSize;
  canvas.height = canvasSize;

  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // center and rotate canvas
  const translateCanvas = canvasSize / 2;
  ctx.translate(translateCanvas, translateCanvas);
  ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);

  // draw from center
  const translateImageX = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? -translateCanvas : (-imageWidth / 2);
  const translateImageY = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? (-imageHeight / 2) : -translateCanvas;
  ctx.drawImage(image, translateImageX, translateImageY); 

  // I got 'cropPlusExport' from another stackoverflow question.
  function cropPlusExport(img, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight) {
    // create a temporary canvas sized to the cropped size
    const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas1.width = cropWidth;
    canvas1.height = cropHeight;
    const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    ctx1.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
    // use the extended from of drawImage to draw the
    // cropped area to the temp canvas
    ctx1.drawImage(img, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight, 0, 0, cropWidth, cropHeight);
    return canvas1.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
  }

  // Start Cropping
  let squareImage = new Image();
  squareImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
  squareImage.onload = () => {
    const sx = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? ((canvasSize - imageHeight) / 2) : 0;
    const sy = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? 0 : ((canvasSize - imageWidth) / 2);
    const sw = imageHeight;
    const sh = imageWidth;
    const data = cropPlusExport(squareImage, sx, sy, sw, sh);

    // Update DOM via angular binding...
    const dataUrl = data.split(",")[1];
    this.imageSource = dataUrl;

    squareImage = null;
  }
```

example html

```
<div class="view">
  <img [src]="imageSource" />
</div>
```

Keep in mind that I am cropping to the natural width and height of the image. So, what's weird is that if I don't crop, then the image quality doesn't change but when I do crop, the image quality changes.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas drawing is lossy, and rotating an image induce hard modifications of the pixels. So indeed, if you start always from the last state, you'll end up adding more and more artifacts to your image.

Simply store the original image somewhere and always start from there instead of using the modified version.

```js
// will fire in a loop
img.onload = e => elem.rotateAndSave(1);

const elem = {
  // store a copy of the original image
  originalimage: img.cloneNode(),
  angle: 0,
  rotateAndSave(degrees) {
    // always use the stored original image
    const image = this.originalimage;
    // keep track of current transform
    this.angle += degrees;
    const imageWidth = image.naturalWidth;
    const imageHeight = image.naturalHeight;
    const startedHorizontalEndedVertical = imageWidth > imageHeight;
    const canvasSize = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? imageWidth : imageHeight;

    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasSize;
    canvas.height = canvasSize;

    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // center and rotate canvas
    const translateCanvas = canvasSize / 2;
    ctx.translate(translateCanvas, translateCanvas);
    ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180);

    // draw from center
    const translateImageX = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? -translateCanvas : (-imageWidth / 2);
    const translateImageY = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? (-imageHeight / 2) : -translateCanvas;
    ctx.drawImage(image, translateImageX, translateImageY);

    // I got 'cropPlusExport' from another stackoverflow question.
    function cropPlusExport(img, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight) {
      // create a temporary canvas sized to the cropped size
      const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas1.width = cropWidth;
      canvas1.height = cropHeight;
      const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
      ctx1.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
      ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
      // use the extended from of drawImage to draw the
      // cropped area to the temp canvas
      ctx1.drawImage(img, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight, 0, 0, cropWidth, cropHeight);
      return canvas1.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
    }

    // Start Cropping
    let squareImage = new Image();
    squareImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
    squareImage.onload = () => {
      const sx = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? ((canvasSize - imageHeight) / 2) : 0;
      const sy = startedHorizontalEndedVertical ? 0 : ((canvasSize - imageWidth) / 2);
      const sw = imageHeight;
      const sh = imageWidth;
      const data = cropPlusExport(squareImage, sx, sy, sw, sh);

      // Update DOM via angular binding...
      img.src = data;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<img crossorigin src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg" id="img">
```

Comment: There is so much loss in one rotation that even this solution is not plausible with my constraints. It feels like there is a way to reduce the artifacts but maybe not. For instance, if I just rotate the image, quality is fine. But cropping after rotating is not? And, just cropping a non-rotated image is fine? Why is it so bad when the two are put together (especially since rotate and crop are done on two different canvases)?

Comment: Also, if the image is a square, quality is fine.

Comment: ? You have some css applied on your image? Quality is fine for me in the snippet.

Comment: Well, I still have to save the image, so if they rotate and then refresh, the image would get pretty bad after about 4 rotations. Not exactly what I want to put in production code.

Comment: Then save the original image and the current transform. Without knowing what you are doing we can't help you. And there is just nothing you can do to preserve original quality of an image when you rotate it.